# BuddyPress - How to add logout in nav menu

Tags: menus, buddypress, navigation

How to add a logout option to the main nav menu (not to the top bar) in BuddyPress?

Comment: Are you using the supplied default theme?

Comment: Yes, Im using the default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20adding%20logout%20to%20menu). Here is a snippit I found I didn't test it but seems logical.

```
 // functions.php
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args)
{
  if(is_user_logged_in())
  {
    $newitems = '<li><a title="Logout" href="'. wp_logout_url('index.php') .'">Logout</a></li>';
    $newitems .= $items;
  }
  else
  {
    $newitems = '<li><a title="Login" href="'. wp_login_url('index.php') .'">Login</a></li>';
    $newitems .= $items;
  }
  return $newitems;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
```

[Source](http://erisds.co.uk/wordpress/snippet-wordpress-3-0-menus-add-a-login-logout-link)